# Set formula critera range to entire column VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to automate a report, (forgive my lack of Excel experience), and come across this error. Which displays #NAME in the cell. The code should select the cell and COUNTIF <1 for all of column E on another page in the workbook. Is this a simple syntax error?

```
    Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(prrSearchResults!E:E,""<""&1)"
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, your criteria can just be: `""<1""` rather than `""<""&1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the **R1C1**

```
Sub qwerty()
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTIF(prrSearchResults!E:E,""<""&1)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select the cell actually - and I would avoid R1C1 formulas for something simple.

As such - I'd just try this:
This would put the formula in the cell

```
Sub test()
    Range("B2").Value = "=COUNTIF(prrSearchResults!E:E,""<""&1)"
End Sub
```

Comment: I  think `Formula` property is more suitable in this case.